# Patch bitbake to use custom `wpa_supplicant.conf`

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I have a `wpa_supplicant.conf` that I want to use at first boot. I tried to patch `poky`'s recipe as follows. This is my `wpa_supplicant_2.6.bbappend`:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_append := ":${THISDIR}/${PN}"
SRC_URI_append = " file://wpa_supplicant.conf"
```

I have the conf file stored relative to the `bbappend` in `wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. Still the original poky conf file is always added to the image.

How can I inject my config file?

(I'm on branch `warrior`)

**NOTE/EDIT:** For quick and efficient problem solving I recommend also discussing issues in the [IRC channel](https://webchat.freenode.net/#yocto) (as also happened in this case). Super helpful people there!

Comment: I had a warning that I should be using {BPN} instead of {PN}. In case anybody in 2024 has issues

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, the recipe is called `wpa-supplicant` and not `wpa_supplicant` so you need to name the bbappend `wpa-supplicant_2.6.bbapend` and not `wpa_supplicant_2.6.bbappend`. Remember, no underscore, no uppercase letter in recipe or package name.

One can check that a bbappend is parsed by using `bitbake-layers show-appends wpa-supplicant`. You'd have seen that your bbappend was not taken into account.

Then, one should usually use `FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend :=` because you want your path to be traversed before all the other ones.
`FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"`

Finally, since the recipe is named `wpa-supplicant` and not `wpa_supplicant`, `${PN}` will be `wpa-supplicant`, thus you need to put your file in `wpa-supplicant/` and not `wpa_supplicant`.

To check in which order paths are traversed for files, one can run `bitbake -e wpa-supplicant | grep -e "^FILESPATH="`, the paths are traversed from leftmost to rightmost. The first file which matches the full path will be taken.

After discussing on IRC with you, I can add that we also figured out that `wpa_supplicant.conf` is installed in the documentation directory but `wpa_supplicant.conf-sane` is the one that will be used as `wpa_supplicant.conf` in the final image for the target. So one would need to name the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file as `wpa_supplicant.conf-sane` in order for it to replace the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file in the final image.

c.f. https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-connectivity/wpa-supplicant/wpa-supplicant_2.6.bb?h=thud#n88 and https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-connectivity/wpa-supplicant/wpa-supplicant_2.6.bb?h=thud#n91